# Swift - How Speech basic operator - Symbol (+, -, ×)?

Tags: swift, speech-recognition, avspeechsynthesizer

I try to set a button to speech the text in a label (with different voices / languages), but the speech is not working very well when there are operator symbols (+, -, ×), any idea to fix this problem?

I tried:

```
//Option 1
TextLabel.text = "1 + 2 - 3 × 4" // Result: "+" = "and" other voice "plus" (ok), "-" = mute, "×" = mute, other voice "X" (letter)

//Option 2
TextLabel.text = "1 ➕ 2 ➖ 3 ✖️ 4" // Result: "+" = plus symbol, "-" = minus symbol, "×" = multiplication symbol
```

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Speech

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    @IBAction func speaker(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (!synth.isSpeaking) {
            let speech = AVSpeechUtterance(string: TextLabel.text!)

            speech.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
            speech.rate = 0.5
            speech.pitchMultiplier = 1
            speech.volume = 1
            synth.speak(speech)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var TextLabel: UILabel!

    //Option 1
    TextLabel.text = "1 + 2 - 3 × 4" // "+" = "and" other voice "plus" (ok), "-" = mute, "×" = mute, other voice "X" (letter)

    //Option 2
    TextLabel.text = "1 ➕ 2 ➖ 3 ✖️ 4" // "+" = plus symbol, "-" = minus symbol, "×" = multiplication symbol
}
```

I expect speech the symbol + (plus), - (minus), ×(times) correctly in different languages with AVSpeechSynthesisVoice, but the Option 1 is not correct or mute some symbol... and the Option 2 is better but reproduce the word "symbol"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...the speech is not working very well when there are operator symbols (+, -, ×), any idea to fix this problem?

To get the most accurate results, you should **remove any ambiguous symbol** *(it isn't possible to reliably detect the context they must be read out)* and replace them with spelled-out forms.

> I expect speech the symbol + (plus), - (minus), ×(times) correctly in different languages...

I suggest to **use `NSLocalizedString(, comment:)`** in order for each one of your symbols to be read out in different languages.

A very simple example is provided hereafter *(remove and replace the symbols)*:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let string1 = "1"
        let string2 = "5"
        let result = "6"

        let finalString = string1 + NSLocalizedString("MyPlus", comment: "") + string2 + NSLocalizedString("MyEqual", comment: "") + result

        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: finalString)
        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }
}
```

Create one `Localizable.strings` for each language where you define the following terms in english for instance:

```
"MyPlus" = " plus ";
"MyEqual" = " is equal to ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the symbols, just use Customizing Pronunciation to replace the speak.

```
import AVFoundation

let text = "1 ➕ 2 ➖ 3 ✖️ 4"
let rangeOne = NSString(string: text).range(of: "➕")
let rangeTwo = NSString(string: text).range(of: "➖")
let rangeThree = NSString(string: text).range(of: "✖️")
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

let pronunciationKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute)
mutableAttributedString.setAttributes([pronunciationKey: "plʌs"], range: rangeOne)

mutableAttributedString.setAttributes([pronunciationKey: "ˈmaɪ.nəs"], range: rangeTwo)

mutableAttributedString.setAttributes([pronunciationKey: "taɪmz"], range: rangeThree)
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: mutableAttributedString)


utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

from [NShipster](https://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/)

> AVUtterance added functionality to control the pronunciation of
>   particular words, which is especially helpful for proper names.
>
> To take advantage of it, construct an utterance using
>   init(attributedString:) instead of init(string:). The initializer
>   scans through the attributed string for any values associated with the
>   AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute, and adjusts pronunciation
>   accordingly.